# Function that returns function based on expression text

Tags: lua

I would like to create a function (call it fcreate) that when given a string, returns a Lua function. For example, I should be able to say

```
f=fcreate("math.sin(x)+math.cos(x)")
print(f(2)) -- evaluates sin(2)+cos(2)
print(f(3)) -- evaluates sin(3)+cos(3)
```

To make things easy, the string will just be a function of x.

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
function fcreate(fs)
  assert(loadstring("local f=function (x) return ".." end"))
  return f
end
```

For some reason the f which is returned is nil.

Comment: Try to declare the local in the outer function scope, then assign to it in the loadstring clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it right. Try this

```
function fcreate(fs)
  return assert(loadstring("return function (x) return " .. fs.." end"))()
end
```

Comment: Hi Luiz Henrique de Figueiredo! That is almost exactly what I came up with, but I put "local x=x" just after "function (x)".

Comment: @John, in your solution, `x` is an upvalue, not a true parameter.

Comment: Thank, so is this solution better than Nicol's solution above?

Comment: @John, to my taste, my solution is better because it creates the precise mathematical function you need.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
function fcreate(fs)
  local f = assert(loadstring("return " .. fs))
  return f
end
```

---

If there are parameters, you can use `...` notation to get them. But if you absolutely need named parameters:

```
function fcreate(fs)
  local f = assert(loadstring("local x = ...; return " .. fs))
  return f
end
```

Comment: but how will the f know that x is the variable?

Comment: @John Smith: A better question would be how you know that `fs` takes the parameter "x". However, if `fs` has some expected parameter notation, see the edit.

Comment: I did say the parameter is x.

Answer (score 0):

CoronaSDK is sand-boxed, so `loadstring`, `dostring`, `loadfile`, and `dofile` are all unavailable.

(this means that there isn't a way to go from a string to lua code at runtime)

Comment: I just put coronasdk to attract more eyeballs. :-)

Comment: @John, Lua has over 700 followers, coronasdk has 10.  Not only is that abusing the tagging system, it's doing so for no reason.